# Neovimにdein.vimをインストールしようとすると失敗する

Tags: vim

[この](http://qiita.com/DialBird/items/0a96910f13586d635dc0)ページと ttp://qiita.com/Ress/items/7e71e007cf8d41a07a1a を参考にしてVimをNeovimで置き換えてdein.vimをインストールしようとしているのですが、引数が必要と出てどうすればいいかわからず困っています。[image: dein.vimのエラー]

環境は以下の通りです
ホスト             : Windows 7 HomePremium 64Bit
仮想環境ソフトウェア  : VirtualBox 5.1.8
ゲスト             : ArchLinux 64Bit
Neovim            : 0.1.7-2

init.vimはinstaller.shを実行して出たコードを以下のようにそのまま貼り付けました。
以下の通りです。ユーザーフォルダはそのままにしました。

```
"dein Scripts-----------------------------
if &compatible
  set nocompatible               " Be iMproved
endif
" Required:
set runtimepath+=/home/tomi/.cache/dein/repos/github.com/Shougo/dein.vim


" Required:
if dein#load_state('/home/tomi/.cache/dein')
  call dein#begin('/home/tomi/.cache/dein')

  " Let dein manage dein
  " Required:
  call 
dein#add('/home/tomi/.cache/dein/repos/github.com/Shougo/dein.vim')

  " Add or remove your plugins here:
  call dein#add('Shougo/neosnippet.vim')
  call dein#add('Shougo/neosnippet-snippets')

  " You can specify revision/branch/tag.
  call dein#add('Shougo/vimshell', { 'rev': '3787e5' })

  " Required:
  call dein#end()
  call dein#save_state()
endif

" Required:
filetype plugin indent on
syntax enable

" If you want to install not installed plugins on startup.
if dein#check_install()
  call dein#install()
endif

"End dein Scripts-------------------------
```

初歩的な質問になりますが、ご回答のほどよろしくお願いします。

Answer (score 2, accepted):

15行目と16行目を分割しているのが原因です。分割せずに1行で書いてください。